# Updating subdocuments in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update some fields to Date objects but I've run into some problems when the fields are located in subdocuments. Probably a super simple question but I just can't get it right..

The collection has the following structure:

```
{
  "dob": "1989-03-12",
  "gender": "M",
  "visits": [
    {
      "date": "2002-03-01",
      "type": "NO23",
    },
    {
      "checked": "2012-03-02",
      "type": "NO11",
    }]
},
{
  "dob": "1970-08-22",
  "gender": "M",
  "visits": [
    {
      "date": "2008-09-01",
      "type": "NO23",
    },
    {
      "checked": "2010-09-02",
      "type": "NO11",
    }]
}, ...
```

I've managed update the **dob:** of every documents with the following in the Mongo console:

```
var cursor = db.collection.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    var doc = cursor.next()
    db.collection.update({_id : doc._id}, {$set : {dob : new Date(doc.dob)}})
}
```

But I can't manage to change the **visits.date**. I've tried the following without success:

```
db.collection.update({"_id" : doc._id}, {$set: {"visits.$.date": new Date(visits.$.date)}})
```

which gives me `JavaScript execution failed: ReferenceError: visits is not defined`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I am not wrong, your query is not correct, you are using $ operator in update part of update() query, which represents position inside 'visits', which comes from the find part of the update() query. In your find query there is no such position ($) inside 'visits' you will get. I am not sure what you want to do from {$set: {"visits.$.date": new Date(visits.$.date)}}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the way you are operating on a field value as `new Date(visits.$.date)` will work. Furthermore using the value of `visits.$.date` such as `2008-09-01` may not work correctly with `new Date()`. Instead you might need to parse it as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587398/1847471. A bit complicated, but here's what i tried:

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]);
}
var cursor = db.collection.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    var doc = cursor.next()
    db.collection.update({_id : doc._id}, {$set : {collection : new Date(doc.collection)}})
    for (var visit in doc.visits) {
      var val = doc.visits[visit].date;
      if (val != undefined) {
        var set_hash = {};
        set_hash["visits."+visit+".date"] = parseDate(val);
        db.collection.update({"_id" : doc._id}, {$set: set_hash});
      }
    }
}
```